# Collect Array from HTML with angular

Tags: php, html, angularjs

I'm getting data out of the db with php, to make it available in a form in HTML.
The li elements look something like this

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="check_list[i]" id="i" value="something">
```

Of course the "i" is replaced with a number in the actual HTML, so the elements have for example `check_list[1]`, `id=[1]` and so on...

How can I now access these ng-models in the controller? I want to iterate over all **existing** `check_list[i]` elements (it shouldn't be hardcoded which elements exist, I want to leave it generic), and collect them, to send all checked elements back to the php script to store it in the db. So I'm trying something like this.

```
    submitForm.insertData = function(){
        var check_list_elements = [];
        for(var i = 1; i <= 83; i++) {
            //add only those ng-models check_list[i], that really exist into check_list_elements
            if ($scope.check_list[i] !== undefined){
                $check_list_elements.push($scope.check_list[i]);
            }
        }
```

But I keep getting

```
Cannot read property '1' of undefined at t.insertData
```

So `$scope.check_list[i]` is obviously wrong.

How is it done correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think without check any checkbox **$scope.check_list** is undefined so you cant read propert 1 of undefined. define $scope.check_list in your controller when initialize your controller or check in in  **submitForm.insertData** function before itarate

```
    submitForm.insertData = function(){
        var check_list_elements = [];
        if($scope.check_list){
           for(var i = 1; i <= 83; i++) {
            //add only those ng-models check_list[i], that really exist into check_list_elements
              if ($scope.check_list[i] !== undefined){
                $check_list_elements.push($scope.check_list[i]);
               }
           }

        }
```